# Java TCP Pinging IP address

Tags: java, tcp, ping

Hello I just wanted to know how to ping an IP Address using the TCP protocol.

I tried this:

```java
public static void sendPingRequest(String ipAddress) throws UnknownHostException, IOException { 
  InetAddress geek = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress); 
  System.out.println("Sending Ping Request to " + ipAddress); 
  if (geek.isReachable(5000)) 
    System.out.println("Host is reachable"); 
  else
    System.out.println("Sorry ! We can't reach to this host"); 
}
```

But this doesn't work, because my Internet Service Provider blocks UDP requests.

Can anyone help me to find out how I need to fix this?

Comment: Try this https://mindchasers.com/dev/ping

Comment: If UDP is blocked there is nothing you can do except use TCP and try to connect to an specific port.

Comment: They don't work. They time out using the methods you said.